# %20 to 0 issue when using batch file to open website

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, web

I am currently writing a batch file to open a site in IE.
In the batch file I wrote:

```
start https://mysite.net/personal/me/Shared%20Documents/1.docx
```

However when I ran the batch file, IE opens up the site:

```
https://mysite.net/personal/me/Shared0Documents/1.docx
```

Note that there is a change from %20 to 0. So naturally, IE showed a 404 error.

How can I make IE open the exact link without modifying it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try double percentage sign: "start https://mysite.net/personal/me/Shared%%20Documents/1.docx"

Comment: Double percent `%%20` worked for me. Whoever made the link used two spaces, so I needed `%%20%%20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a function and call into it with `%%%%2` like so:

```
@echo off

call :test %%%%1 %%%%2 %%%%3 %%%%4 %%%%5 %%%%6 %%%%7 %%%%8 %%%%9
goto end

:test
start https://mysite.net/personal/me/Shared%20Documents/1.docx

:end
```

Or IF you wanted to mod the links, you can do this:

```
start https://mysite.net/personal/me/Shared%%20Documents/1.docx
```